# Where do you load the .text segment in an a.out file to

Tags: c, format, loading, osdev

I am trying to use the a.out format for my bootloader and I recall being able to do it in the past. ELF doesn't support 16 bit very well and produces a lot of undefined behavior when linked with C code. I am using BCC/dev86 to compile the code. The problem I'm having is finding any documentation on to where in memory you are supposed to place the text segment on a position-dependent 8086/real mode a.out file. It's in the header where the entry point is but I am unable to locate any sort of documentation of the loading of an a.out. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: can you use the boot loader of MBR and dump the base physical address from there ?

Comment: I assume you need this information? https://wiki.osdev.org/MBR_(x86)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the first part of a bootloader (the 16 bit part) is written in assembly. This is mainly because a bootloader needs to do such low level tasks that using c is not really worth it. Once the bootloader gets itself to protected or long mode, it can use c. Another reason why using c is a bad idea for a bootloader is that a bootloader's task usually is to get the system into a state in which the kernel can start executing. On x86 this usually means going to protected mode. This involves linking some 16bit c code to some 32 bit c code (and maybe even some 64 bit code). This is *really* hard to do.

If you really think you want to continue with what you're doing: an a.out file is just an elf file. In bootloaders the cpu starts execution at address 0x7c00. So I suppose you should link the .text section to 0x7c00.

One more comment Id like to make, is that on modern cpus you don't even need to worry much about how to get sections from an a.out file. Usually UEFI can just boot elf files directly. And Qemu can as well.

Comment: thank you for your input but an a.out is not an ELF file. It is a predacessor to COFF for the original UNIX. However all you need to do to load it i figured is load it like a COM executable if you use the SEVENTH edition unix header with a 16 bit magic. once you have a 16 bit a.out you tell the linker where to put the text and data address and then load it there from the boot sector and jump to the entry

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, it's not elf indeed. Hope you could fix it anyway :)